# Is there a way to make a HtmlGenericControl child control onClick event override the parent onClick event?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there a way for the onclick event of a parent control to not be fired if it is the child control which is clicked? Sample code below, where an image is the child control.

When the image is clicked, both OnParentControlClicked() and onChildControlClicked() are fired, when I only want onChildControlClicked(). Is there any way to do this?

```
HtmlGenericControl myControl = new HtmlGenericControl();
myControl.Attributes.Add("onclick", "OnParentControlClicked();");

HtmlImage myImg = new HtmlImage();
myImg.Src = myImgSourcePath;
myImg.Attributes.Add("onclick", "onChildControlClicked();");

myControl.Controls.Add(myImg);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can to stop event propagation from child to parent, if at method onChildControlClicked will call method stopPropogation

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397715.aspx - if using ms ajax
http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/ - if using jQuery

Comment: Thanks, that worked. As an aside, you need to use event.cancelBubble = true instead, if using IE8 or below.